# quasi likelihood for ungrouped binary data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, quasi-likelihood

I read in one of the textbooks that for ungrouped binary data the dispersion parameter should always be $\phi = 1$.

Do you know why it is the case?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386675/what-are-weights-in-a-binary-glm-and-how-to-calculate-them/386913#386913

Comment: @GordonSmyth In this link you have written that $var(y_i) = \mu_i(1-\mu_i)/w_i$. I suppose $1/w_i$ is the variance inflation factor. I wonder how did you conclude that "it is impossible for the variance to be anything other than $\mu_i(1−\mu_i)$". What is the logic behind this statement?

Comment: It is one line of mathematics. Try computing the variance for yourself and you will see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $Y$ is a binary random variable that takes value 1 with probability $p$ and 0 with probability $1-p$.

Then
$$E(Y)=0(1-p)+1p=p$$
and
$$\mbox{var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2=0^2(1-p)+1^2p-p^2=p(1-p).$$

This shows that the variance of $Y$ is a function of the mean, i.e., the variance is completely determined by the mean.
Hence there are no unknown parameters to estimate and there cannot be any overdispersion or underdispersion.

Comment: So, in the case of the binomial distribution, the variance depends on $n$ and $p$, so that overdispersion is a result of impact caused by $n$ and $p$?

Comment: @shani Overdispersion is caused by dependence. If $n>1$ and the trials are independent then the sum is binomial, i.e., not overdispersed. If the trials are positively dependent then the sum is over-dispersed relative to binomial. This is explained in the link I gave you in my comment above. If $n=1$ there is only one trial, so nothing to be correlated with, hence no overdispersion.

Comment: @shani The other way for overdispersion to arise is when there are $n>1$ trials and the trials are independent but the success probability is not constant from one trial to another. That will also lead to a variable that is overdispersed relative to binomial. Again, this cannot occur for $n=1$. In summary, the binomial distribution assumes $n$ independent trials with constant success probability. Failure of either of the assumptions (independence or constancy) can lead to overdispersion. Neither failure can occur when $n=1$.